# MobX autorun doesn't get dependency it should

Tags: javascript, mobx

#### This code I took from https://mobx.js.org/understanding-reactivity.html

```
import { makeAutoObservable, autorun, getDependencyTree  } from "mobx";

class Message {
  title;
  author;
  likes;
  constructor(title, author, likes) {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.likes = likes;
  }

  updateTitle(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}

let message = new Message("Foo", { name: "Michel" }, ["Joe", "Sara"]);

const disposer = autorun(() => {
  console.log(message.title);
});

console.log(getDependencyTree(disposer));
message.updateTitle("Bar");
message.updateTitle("gasdg");
```

But in consolse I get this:

```
Foo
index.js:114 {name: 'Autorun@2'}
```

It doesn't pick up `message.title` as dependency, please help me understand why!

Comment: Class properties seem to be very dependent on environment. The code in your question doesn't work in e.g. a Stack Overflow code snippet, but [it works in a CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-cannon-11wxpk?file=/src/index.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By default](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#limitations) `make(Auto)Observable` only supports properties that are already defined, so you need to define every property inside constructor or make it nullable like that: `author = null`, or add default value `likes = 0`:

```
class Message {
  // Or add default values here
  title = '';
  author = null;
  likes = 0;
  constructor(title, author, likes) {
    // Initialise properties as first thing
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.likes = likes;

    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  updateTitle(title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you might want to try to reconfigure [how class properties initialisation works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), using `useDefineForClassFields` TS compiler flag:

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "useDefineForClassFields": true
},
```

Comment: as a Tholle said it works like that in different environment,
But thanks to you know I'm better understanding how make(Auto)Observable works, default values helped!)